# Prime or perfect number program in C

Tags: c

I've made a program that checks if a given positive integer is a prime or perfect number.The problem I'm facing is I created a function "readNumber" that works as a check loop to ensure that input is a positive integer.But if I enter a negative value and then an acceptable one it shows previous values aswell.I attach a screenshot of the command prompt text to make myself more clear.

Below is my code

[image: Screenshot]

```
#include<stdio.h>

  int checkperfectnumber(int);
 
  int checkprimenumber(int);

  int readNumber(int);

int main(){
          int num, x, y, result;

          printf("\nGive a positive integer number: \n");
          scanf("%d",&num);

          y = readNumber(num);

          x = checkperfectnumber(num);

          result = checkprimenumber(num);


          if (num == 1)
          printf("1 is nor a prime neither a perfect number");
          else if (x == num)
          printf("%d is a perfect number\n",num);
          else if ( result == 1 )
          printf("%d is a prime number.\n", num);
          else
          printf("%d is nor prime neither a perfect number.\n", num);
          return 0;

          }

          //perfect number function
          int checkperfectnumber(int numbr){
          int a=1, sum=0;
          while(a < numbr){
          if(numbr % a == 0)
          sum=sum+a;
          a++;
          }
          return(sum);
          }

          //prime number function
          int checkprimenumber(int a)
          {
          int c;
          for ( c = 2 ; c <= a - 1 ; c++ )
          {
          if ( a%c == 0 )
          return 0;
          }
          return 1;
          }

          //input check function
          int readNumber(int b){
          while (b < 0)
            {
            printf("Wrong input.\nPlease insert a positive integer.");
            main();
            break;
            }


          }
```

Comment: your screenshot is of text and it should be text.

Comment: @DanielFarrell you're right thank you

Comment: `main` calling `main` recursively does not look right...

Comment: You can use the `edit` button to replace the screenshot of plain text with plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix is have the program exit after executing `main()` from `readNumber()`.
To do this, Add `#include <stdlib.h>` and replace `break;` in the function `readNumber()` to `exit(0);`.

Better solution is having the function `readNumber()`, not `main()`, read numbers and stop calling `main()` recursively.
It will be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int checkperfectnumber(int);

int checkprimenumber(int);

int readNumber(void);

int main(){
    int num, x, y, result;

    printf("\nGive a positive integer number: \n");

    num = readNumber();

    x = checkperfectnumber(num);

    result = checkprimenumber(num);


    if (num == 1)
        printf("1 is nor a prime neither a perfect number");
    else if (x == num)
        printf("%d is a perfect number\n",num);
    else if ( result == 1 )
        printf("%d is a prime number.\n", num);
    else
        printf("%d is nor prime neither a perfect number.\n", num);
    return 0;

}

//perfect number function
int checkperfectnumber(int numbr){
    int a=1, sum=0;
    while(a < numbr){
        if(numbr % a == 0)
        sum=sum+a;
        a++;
    }
    return(sum);
}

//prime number function
int checkprimenumber(int a)
{
    int c;
    for ( c = 2 ; c <= a - 1 ; c++ )
    {
        if ( a%c == 0 )
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

//input check function
int readNumber(void){
    for (;;)
    {
        int b;
        scanf("%d",&b);
        if (b >= 0) return b; /* 0 is not positive, but this condition is !(b < 0) */
        printf("Wrong input.\nPlease insert a positive integer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the use for the ";;" inside for?

Comment: @EvangelosNikolopoulos That is a normal `for` loop without any intialization, condition or post-loop-action. It just runs endlessly unless you break/return out of it.